# What does #!perl do exactly?

Tags: bash

I recently received a perl script with the first line

```
#!perl
```

This of course doesn't work but I would like to know exactly what it does.  Can anyone help?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: For an invalid shebang like that, it's just a hint, could be for the editor or for the user.

Comment: @glennjackman The thing is that it does do something if you try it. Maybe it just looks for perl in the current directory?

Comment: you have to specify the path to the perl interpreter in the shebang line.

Comment: @AvinashRaj OK so if you don't, it just looks in the directory that you called the script from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and is used (in Unix) to specify which interpreter binary should be used to run a script.

It's a very nice mechanism, especially together with the way the [file system permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) can be used to turn a script file into something the shell (and program loader) consider to be executable.

It seems [the interpreter name must be absolute](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#issues). The linked text says that a relative name (like the bare `perl` here) will be interpreted as `./perl`, so it might work *if executed from the directory the `perl` binary is in*. Not a very common use-case but at least it could work if used that way, i.e. if you want to wrap a `perl` binary with a script, you *want* that script to run the binary that's in the same place as the script, and not use absolute paths to pick some other binary. Haven't tested this.

A more typical approach (at least in Linux) is to use the [`env`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env) program to pick the perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Comment: It doesn't work even if perl is in the current $PATH which is one reason I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you give the shebang line like this,

```
#!perl
```

it will look for the perl interpreter in the current directory. If the perl interpreter exists in the current directory, then the perl script will start to execute otherwise it shows `bad interpreter` error.